# Magento2 : Cannot add order comment "We cannot add order history" error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5, order-history

Magento2.3.5 I have trouble of adding comment to customers order. I can sent to one store view (Thai) but another store view show "We cannot add order history". in the order comment box. Anyone know how to fix?[image: here]

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Cheers
Rob

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?